# How to use TextView in MainActivity which has been initialized for BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, textview, baseadapter

I initialized TextView inside BaseAdapter and now I want to use that initialized TextView in My Activity. I am passing TextView from constructor but no luck. Please help me. My code is here

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    contactListItems = contactList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_student_data, null);
    }

    TextView presentView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.presentView);
     }
```

This presentView I want to use in my MainActivity. guide me.

Comment: where is main activity and base adapter code. need more info\

Comment: why do you need to use this `TextView` in your activity, why not just using it in your adapter.

Comment: Inside the list, which`TextView` you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your activity using listview

```
int position = 0;
listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
View wantedView = adapter.getView(position, null, listview);
```